# Can I set a variable in Angular template, and reuse it on other or child elements?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular template, like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <p>Name: {{ getHeroAttribute(hero)?.name || '' }}</p>
  <p>Skills: {{ getHeroAttribute(hero)?.skills || '' }}</p>
</div>
```

From the template above, `getHeroAttribute()` function will be called multiple times on render. Can I create an attribute on the element parent? So that I can get `name` and `skills` without multiple calls of `getHeroAttribute()`?

Let's assume that I must use this function to get its attribute, I cannot use `hero.name` or `hero.skills` to show the values.

Comment: Can you share the sample data and implementation of `getHeroAttribute` method? Think that you can transform the `heroes` array data before displaying and in the transformation, you can manipulate the data for projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's a bad idea use a function in .html because this is called several times.

But you can "minimize" the effect if only call a time and use *ngIf as

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <ng-content *ngIf="getHeroAttribute(hero) as dataHero">
    <p>Name: {{ dataHero?.name || '' }}</p>
    <p>Skills: {{ dataHero?.skills || '' }}</p>
  </ng-content>
</div>
```

This approach has the problem in the function not return a value so you can
use, see the `|| {name:'',skills:''}`

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <ng-content *ngIf="getHeroAttribute(hero) || {name:'',skills:''} as dataHero">
    <p>Name: {{ dataHero?.name || '' }}</p>
    <p>Skills: {{ dataHero?.skills || '' }}</p>
  </ng-content>
</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <ng-content *ngIf="{data:getHeroAttribute(hero)} as dataHero">
    <p>Name: {{ dataHero.data?.name || '' }}</p>
    <p>Skills: {{ dataHero.data?.skills || '' }}</p>
  </ng-content>
</div>
```

But really the best bet is "extends" our heroes array

```
//after you get the heroes
this heroesExtends=this.heroes.map(x=>({...x,data:getHeroAttribute(x)})

//use heroesExtends
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroesExtends">
    <p>Name: {{ hero.data?.name || '' }}</p>
    <p>Skills: {{ hero.data?.skills || '' }}</p>
  </ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. function call are not in general bad (see signals, small and correctly implemented function return the same object etc.) 2. please examples for the new control flow. 3. you examples with || should be replaced with ?? or removed ;)

Comment: thanks for the solution, just remembered to use 'as' keyword in the template. as of this solution do you have link to the documentation page attached? thank you once again!